# Groovy: Generate random string from given character set

Tags: string, groovy, random

Using Groovy, I'd like to generate a random sequence of characters from a given regular expression.

- Allowed charaters are: `[A-Z0-9]`
- Length of generated sequence: 9

Example: `A586FT3HS`

However, I can't find any code snippet which would help me. If using regular expressions is too complicated, I'll be fine defining the allowed set of characters manually.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If you don't want to use apache commons, or aren't using Grails, an alternative is:

```
def generator = { String alphabet, int n ->
  new Random().with {
    (1..n).collect { alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join()
  }
}

generator( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')).join(), 9 )
```

but again, you'll need to make your `alphabet` yourself...  I don't know of anything which can parse a regular expression and extract out an alphabet of passing characters...

Comment: I get "No such DSL method 'nextInt' " when I use this.

Comment: You using it in Jenkins? No idea if this will work in Jenkins

Comment: Yep Jenkins. I ended up using the Apache import

Comment: @ChrisF You probably needed to use full name, or import: java.util.Random.nextInt()
I will be testing this in a while.

Answer (score 64):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils

String charset = (('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')).join()
Integer length = 9
String randomString = RandomStringUtils.random(length, charset.toCharArray())
```

The imported class `RandomStringUtils` is already on the Grails classpath, so you shouldn't need to add anything to the classpath if you're writing a Grails app.

### Update

If you only want alphanumeric characters to be included in the String you can replace the above with

```
String randomString = org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(9, true, true)
```

Comment: You can also use `@Grab(group='commons-lang', module='commons-lang', version='2.4')` and then 
`import org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils`in standard groovy script

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils` now has `randomAlphaNumeric(int count)`

Comment: You may get "org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils random int boolean boolean". Just follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412951/1092815 

Answer (score 8):

For SoupUI users:

```
def generator = { String alphabet, int n ->
  new Random().with {
    (1..n).collect { alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join()
  }
}
randomValue = generator( (('A'..'Z')+('0'..'9')+('a'..'z')).join(), 15 )
testRunner.getTestCase().setPropertyValue("randomNumber", randomValue);
```

Comment: For special characters like _, ., - which will be the escaping solution ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a single line command/statement to generate random text string

```
print new Random().with {(1..9).collect {(('a'..'z')).join()[ nextInt((('a'..'z')).join().length())]}.join()}
```

or

```
def randText = print new Random().with {(1..9).collect {(('a'..'z')).join()[ nextInt((('a'..'z')).join().length())]}.join()}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a string with your alphabet, then
do this 9 times:

1. Create a [random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) number
2. Find [the corresponding character](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) in your alphabet.
3. [Append](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#append%28char%29) it to the result

Answer (score 1):

This code is pure Groovy I found on the web:

```
def key
def giveMeKey(){
    String alphabet = (('A'..'N')+('P'..'Z')+('a'..'k')+('m'..'z')+('2'..'9')).join() 
    def length = 6
     key = new Random().with {
           (1..length).collect { alphabet[ nextInt( alphabet.length() ) ] }.join()
             }
            return key
        }
```

The return string is good enough for local use:

```
BFx9PU
MkbRaE
FKvupt
gEwjby
Gk2kK6
uJmzLB
WRJGKL
RnSUQT
```

Comment: So your example alphabet omits some characters because they might look similar in some fonts?  lower case 'L' and the digit one.  Along with upper case letter 'O' and the digit zero?  Do I understand your reasoning?  (I realize it's just an example.)

Comment: And I don't understand what's the purpose of the `i=0;i<50;i++` loop?

Comment: @Wyck The generated string contains a random number of uppercase, lowercase letters, and numbers. I've updated the answer and as you can see the output has a different set of upper, lower case letters and numbers. 
Looping statement is irrlevent to the answer.

Comment: I had two problems getting this to work in Jenkins pipeline.  First: I had to change `.join()` to `.join('')`.  to avoid `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.join() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`.  And I had to rewrite without the `with` closure and just do `def rand = new Random()` and then use `rand.nextInt` to avoid `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'nextInt' found among steps`