# Dynamic values in Rest API using JMeter

Tags: api, testing, post, jmeter, payload

I have payload POST call:

```
{  

   "tenantName":"loki",

 "owner":
 {
    "country": "india",
    "firstName": "raj",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "locale": "in",
    "organization": "softwareag",
    "phone": "9789155778",
    "title": "mr",
    "userName": "raraj@softwareag.com",
    "email": "raraj@softwareag.com",
    "password":"V2VsY29tZUAxMjM0"
 },
  "products": [
    "cumulocity",
    "b2b"
  ]
}
```

In that payload, the tenant name is unique, How to pass different values for each post call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [__RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) to randomize name, for example 5 lower case letters:

```
${__RandomString(5,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,)}
```

> RandomString function returns a random String of length using characters in chars to use

Or load name values from [CSV Data set config](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/read-data-from-csv-file-using-csv-data-set-config-in-jmeter/)

Comment: @surya great, you can accept the answer if it helped, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: is there any otherway, using script?

Comment: @surya yes see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138164/groovy-generate-random-string-from-given-character-set/8138604#8138604

Comment: can we save that tenant name variable, because it picks random value.In another api payload, i need to pass the same value which the tenant name picks?

Comment: @surya yes, add the variable name in the after the comma (last parameter) `${__RandomString(5,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,YOURVARIABLENAME)}`

Comment: can we use that saved variable in path...?

Comment: @surya yes using `${YOURVARIABLENAME}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in order to call [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic-int-) method like:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(4),)}
```

replace `4` with the number of your choice to make the random string shorter or longer

[image]

The function can be inlined directly into your request body

```
{
  "tenantName": "${__groovy(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(4),)}",
  "owner": {
    "country": "india",
    "firstName": "raj",
    "lastName": "kumar",
    "locale": "in",
    "organization": "softwareag",
    "phone": "9789155778",
    "title": "mr",
    "userName": "raraj@softwareag.com",
    "email": "raraj@softwareag.com",
    "password": "V2VsY29tZUAxMjM0"
  },
  "products": [
    "cumulocity",
    "b2b"
  ]
}
```

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)